# How can I print graph using AJAX in django?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am creating a weather forecast APP and on the home page a date input box is given. Upon entering the date and  clicking on submit graph should be displayed. I have created an url which gives a JSON string for next days of temperature. I am a beginner so I am not able to figure out the error. Please help me out
here is my code:

```
$('.submit-btn').click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/plot/ (http://127.0.0.1:8000/plot/2017-03-10)" + $("#id_date").val() , function(data){
      plotGraph(data);
    });
});
function plotGraph(data){
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    columns: [data.temp],
    axes: {
      data1: 'temperature'
    }
  },
  axis: {
    y: {
      max: 40,
      min: 0,
       }
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is the `(http://127.0.0.1:8000/plot/2017-03-10)` part of the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

To view javascript errors you need to do the following:

If Chrome browser:

`On Mac - ⌘ + Shift + C. 
On Windows / Linux - Ctrl + Shift + C OR F12.`

Then click on the console tab, if you find any lines red in colour then by clicking on them you will get to know the location of the error.